If I put worms that aren't moving back into the fridge, will the continue to move/come back alive?
When I was fishing, I was using night crawlers and red worms. The red worms worked pretty well, but after a while the worms stopped moving. I was pretty sure they were dead but I wasn't 100% sure. I was wondering if I put them back into the fridge, will they start moving/come back alive?
As an experiment, I put dead worms into the refrigerator, and as far as I could tell, they did not revive.  So I think the answer is NO, but I am asking you because you have more experience.

If anything, the fridge will slow them down and make them not move. Worms will be poikilothermic so they should move less in the fridge. I doubt it would revive any dead worms.

If the worms stopped moving because they got cold, putting them in a fridge would not activate them but would keep them in the same slowed down state and allow them to reactivate when they warm up later.
The better test for that is to get them warmer immediately, like closing the container and get it in a warmer spot, like inside your winter coat.
On the other hand, if they stopped moving because they are dead, storing them longer will not bring them to life.
If your fishing is not in cold weather, say the same temperature as inside a fridge or colder, the chances of them having died are much higher than the chances of them having gone too cold.
No reports of humans bringing dead beings back to life has turned out to be reliable.

Well, CPR not withstanding…

If someone has a heart that stopped but can be revived by CPR they have not really died yet. With modern medical technology the definition of dead has changed.

Without CPR they aren’t waking up.
